# javascript files cant reload when struts2 page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, struts2, requirejs

Here is my problem, I'm using Angular and Require.js with Struts2 and lets say i have the URL

`http://localhost:6666/struts-context/action/#/angular-fragment`

and a resource in

`http://localhost:6666/struts-context/scripts/script.js`,

when i hit the refresh button or F5 on this URL, my "struts-context" get lost, and the server try to find the script on

`http://localhost:6666/scripts/script.js`,

is like the URL `http://localhost:6666/struts-context/action/#/angular-fragment` is not interpreted by struts.

That is all, thanks for any response.

Comment: edit your question and show js including statement in your jsp. That statement needs to be verified to check how you include js file as resource in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<s:url>` tag

```
 <s:url action="scripts/script.js" var="jsURL"></s:url>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="${jsURL}"></script>
```

Comment: If you want to leave comment you can do it under the post, don't needed to post irrelevant content because it doesn't answer.